# Deploy with r.js and bower

Tags: requirejs, bower, minify, concatenation, r.js

I'm pretty new to using npm, bower etc. and deploying with it. Previously I haven't had a decent workflow or any way of setting up my projects easily on another enivornment, but I thought better late than never.

I can't, however, wrap my head around how to deploy this, i.e. concatenating and minifying.
Below is my project structure:

```
root
│
└───app
    │   index.html
    │
    ├───bower_components
    |   <all components>
    │
    ├───js
    |   ├── modules
    │   |   main.js
    |   |
    |   └── plugins
    |       <amd enabled plugins>
    |
    scripts
    |  build.sh
    |
```

The project runs fine in development. I have used [grunt-bower-requirejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bower-requirejs) to wire my bower dependencies to main.js.

Now I'm at a stage where I'd like to deploy this and see how it works. My goal is to minify and concatenate my bower dependenices and my modules using r.js. I've created a build file for r.js that looks like this:

```
({
    appDir: "../app",
    baseUrl: "js/mdoules",
    dir: "../build",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ],
    paths: {
        aPlugin: "../plugins/aPlugin",
        aBowerDep: "../../bower_components/aBowerDep"
    },
    shim: {
        <some non AMD stuff>
    }
})
```

this is called from the script build.sh.

The script copies all files from the app directory to the build directory. I have uploaded the resulting build file [here](http://tny.cz/0589d6a0) if it is to any help. There are a couple of problems here that I don't know how to solve:

1. *All* files from bower_components end up in my build folder, not just the necessary files I've pointed out in r.js build file. How do I get the necessary files only?
2. Files get minified, but not concatenated, they are still located in their original directories.
3. I get a resulting file in build/js/modules that is called main.js, but I have no idea what ended up here. It's a total of 9200 rows unminified, and only jQuery is more than that. It also contains a lot of comments from all the bower dependencies I have, but all of them are not in the file.

I also have a couple of questions when and if I get this up and running:

- When loading the main script with require, can I point out a concatenated and minified file that contains requirejs?
- Same question but regarding the main module, cant I point it out as data-main?

To clarify, can I do this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="all_modules" src="all_bower_dependencies.js"></script>
```

instead of this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/modules/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Am I using bower incorrectly? Is it bad form to minify these dependencies? I would really appreciate any help I could get. Please tell me if I'm doing something way crazy here.